# Why not grid fins on stage 1 of Blue Origin's New Glenn?

Tags: blue-origin, new-shepard, fins, new-glenn

New Glenn has four fins, but, unlike Falcon 9's, they are not grid fins. Instead, they seem to be standard airplane fins---each a single surface. So I'm wondering: what are the advantages of standard fins over grid fins in rockets, and when might you prefer one over the other?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the solid fin as seen above could be used for both ascent stabilization and descent stabilization. It's also a simpler design since it doesn't need to fold flat. Advantage of a grid fin would be that heat dissipation is easier. There is a much greater surface area to volume ratio.